# FixedThreadPool memory leak

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, memory-leaks, threadpoolexecutor

I have a `Stream<String>` and performing some actions on its items, which includes processing String and writing it to file.

Having the following groovy code, and processing **1 million items** i'm running into the **OutOfMemoryError**.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

stream.forEach { item ->
    executorService.execute {
        handle(item)
    }
}

executorService.shutdown()
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
```

After some profiling, i've found out that the Runnable tasks are not handled by gc and **kept alive within the BlockingQueue** until the app fails.

Why ExecutorService keeps the finished Runnable in the queue? and how it's supposed to be cleaned up?

Comment: It doesn't. Your diagnostic is wrong. The queue contains tasks that wait before being executed.

Comment: That doesn't sound especially likely - in order to get the item in the queue to execute it, it has to be removed. So if they're staying in the queue, they're never actually being executed.

Comment: @AndyTurner meaning i should try to decrease the queue size? What would happen in that case?

Comment: @ikryvorotenko try it. That wasn't actually what I was suggesting, though (I wasn't really suggesting anything, just making an observation).

Comment: @AndyTurner yep, now i'm getting RejectedExecutionException. Seems like i need to make the extra Runnable tasks to be run in main thread if there's no space in a queue. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: or you can increase memory limit for the virtual machine.

Comment: The Runnables almost don't have any state anyway, and creating 1 million of them won't consume much memory. You need to figure out what actually eats that memory. What does handle() do?

Comment: @JBNizet these Runnable tasks keep the reference to these String objects, which are quite heavy sometimes.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. And we don't know what "these String objects" are, where they come from, what the runnables do with them, etc.

Comment: Or it's just that you don't process fast enough and the executor queue is growing therefore the memory footprint increase

Comment: @JBNizet it looks like i was mistaken when said that there's only CPU operations. There's some transformation of String and writing it to file. I may assume that because of that the queue is filled up so fast. Is there any way to block the ES when the queue is full?

Comment: You can use a bounded queue, and use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html. But it would be much easier to help if you posted your code and explained, precisely, what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @JBNizet the CallerRunsPolicy helped. It looks like i put to ES more tasks then it can handle. Thanks for help

Comment: Profile it. You say that you are writing to file. How are you closing those streams?

Comment: Have you used jheap or YourKit to analyze the heap when the OOM exception occurs?  My guess is the stream is that either the stream is read in very quickly and you run out of memory almost immediately or your have an inner class reference holding all of the runnables in memory.

Comment: Can you please provide profiler  report .Memory leak means after GC still some unused object in your heap.From your use-case seems not processed items are there .so as suggested above put some rejection policy or save on db and process batch by batch.

Comment: this program does not declare any BlockingQueue . What queue do you mean?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov the Queue is declared within default FixedThreadPool constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory leak was caused because the BlockingQueue was filled up faster then ExecutorService pulled the tasks from it.

This was caused because iterating over stream with `forEach` method is pretty fast but tasks are running some more time.

Here's the solution I applied

```
def processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    processors, processors,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000),
    new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
)
```

Which basically just restrict the BlockingQueue size and make sure the master thread would take the job if the queue is full.

Thanks to @JBNizet and others for help in comments above.